# Customize Chartjs 2.x tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

What you see on the picture has been created by `chartjs` 1.x  version . As you can see at hover on each point i have  same tooltip for both datasets for each corresponding point.

[image]

But after upgrade our `chartjs` to version 2 , i can show the tooltip for each point seperately .( look at picture )

[image]

How can i have the old style tooltip like chartjs version 1.x ( like first picture ) ?

Is there any settings or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `options` set `tooltips.mode` to `label`

```
options: {
......
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
    },
.......
}
```

```js
var chartColors = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(231,233,237)'
};

var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : -1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
}
var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
      fill: false,
    }, {
      label: "My Second dataset",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
      borderColor: chartColors.blue,
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor()
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Month'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:75%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution :)